# Interfacing zlib with ActiveTcl 8.5?

Tags: tcl, zlib, activetcl

I'm trying to use the zlib extension in ActiveTcl 8.5 in order to save out a compressed blob to a file.  Both ActiveTcl 8.5.5 and 8.5.6 on win32 have a zlibtcl 1.2.3 extension.  I've tried both:

```
package require zlibtcl
```

and

```
load zlibtcl123.dll
```

Which both seem to indicate that the extension is properly loaded.  However, I can't seem to figure out what command is necessary to access the extension.  I am aware that ActiveTcl 8.6b1 onwards has the zlib functionality built in (http://wiki.tcl.tk/4610), however I need to deploy to existing systems that must use 8.5.x.

As far as I can tell, loading the extension does not add any new commands to the interpreter, which is quite confusing.  Running a **strings** on the dll does not seem to reveal any additional information.

Note: my backup plan is to SWIG zlib, but I'd prefer to use the existing extension if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You might have more luck with the vfs::zip package.  There is an example on comp.lang.tcl [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.tcl/tree/browse_frm/thread/2a9317f4aeb26920/6ba43633b72df121?rnum=1&q=lemburg&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fcomp.lang.tcl%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F2a9317f4aeb26920%2F33cecc0122085ae7%3Flnk%3Dgst%26q%3Dlemburg%26#doc_33cecc0122085ae7).

Comment: Good thought.  I just tried this and vfs::zip does not appear to be part of the default ActiveTcl 8.5.5 install... and I kind of need a solution for this runtime environment.

Comment: It's certainly part of the 8.4 ActiveTcl install.  I think that they really slimmed down the number of default packages that came with 8.5 - if you want to restrict yourself to the basic 8.5 install you are going to struggle.  It's easily downloadable for 8.5 using teacup.

Answer (score 1):

zlibtcl is used only by the Img package to handle the compression in image formats like PNG.  As suggested above, try vfs::zip. The Trf package is also worthwhile looking into. See http://wiki.tcl.tk/479

Answer (score 1):

You can get a copy of the zlib package from [equi4](http://www.equi4.com/pub/tk/tars/zlib.tar.gz), who provide it as part of their support for the `tclkit` Tcl interpreter/packaging system. It doesn't support the full interface used in 8.6, but it does have enough that you can compression and decompression.

Or you can just use `tclkit` instead of `tclsh`/`wish` and have the zlib package already built in.